# incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 in Oga gem

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, html-parsing

I am using an XML/HTML parser called [Oga](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/oga).

I am attempting to crawl this URL: http://www.johnvanderlyn.com and parse the body for text, like so:

```
 def get_page
    body = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(@url))
    document = Oga.parse_html(body)
  end

document = get_page    
words = document.css('body').text
```

When I get this error:

`/gems/oga-2.7/lib/oga/xml/node_set.rb:276:in block in text': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)`

That is related to this [bit of code here](https://github.com/YorickPeterse/oga/blob/master/lib/oga/xml/node_set.rb#L271-L281).

What could be causing this and how can I fix it? Is there a way for me to fix it locally, or do I have to fork the gem, fix that method and then use my fork?

Thoughts?

Comment: I just executed the code above without any problem. The bit of code you linked has nothing to do with the glitch, that is the issue of `body` is being interpreted in wrong encoding. Try `body = body.force_encoding 'UTF-8'` before parsing a document.

Comment: @mudasobwa Perfect. That works brilliantly. If you add that as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit of code you linked has nothing to do with the glitch, that is the issue of body is being interpreted in wrong encoding. Try adding `body = body.force_encoding 'UTF-8'` before parsing a document:

```
def get_page
  body = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(@url)).force_encoding 'UTF-8'
  document = Oga.parse_html(body)
end
```

Comment: I can't make Oga respect the encoding: `Oga.parse_html("<html>&#0128;</body>".force_encoding("cp1252")).at_css("html").text.b
ytes`. This has to become a Euro character but it becomes something else.

Comment: Maybe the website I'm accessing is wrong by emitting such literal as `&#0128;` and it's just invalid and that's there is no correct way to process it? This `Oga.parse_html("<html>&#0128;</body>").at_css("html").text.force_encoding("cp1252").encode("utf-8")` somehow prepends a garbage byte.